# MongoDB only works when run as root on Ubuntu - data directory issue

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, mongodb, chown

I installed MongoDB with the [official packages](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Ubuntu+and+Debian+packages) (mongodb-stable), and followed the [Quickstart guide](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Quickstart+Unix) which includes:

> By default MongoDB will store data in
>   `/data/db`, but it won't automatically
>   create that directory. To create it,
>   do:
>
> ```
> $ sudo mkdir -p /data/db/
> $ sudo chown `id -u` /data/db
> ```
>
> You can also tell MongoDB to use a
>   different data directory, with the
>   `--dbpath` option.

MongoDB will only start if I run `sudo mongod` - if I try and run just `mongod` I get the error:

```
Mon Mar 14 15:27:07 [initandlisten] couldn't open /data/db/test.ns errno:13 Permission denied
Mon Mar 14 15:27:07 [initandlisten]   couldn't open file /data/db/test.ns terminating
Mon Mar 14 15:27:07 dbexit:
```

What gives?

Comment: i wish all questions were asked this well.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You created `/data/db` as root so it has those permissions. You can change the permissions to your user account, or whatever you have mongo running as.

```
chown -R username /data/db
```

or `/data`

You can also set a group

```
chown -R username.groupname
```

The `-R` does it recursively, so it will affect all the files you've created running mongoDB as root already.

Comment: Any benefit to leaving the owner as root and just assigning a group? Or is it better to specifically set the owner as a user?

Comment: Thanks, I was chowning the directory to mongodb:mongodb instead of my username:my group.

Comment: Remember that you maybe have to run sudo infront of chown -R username /data/db

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same issue on RHEL 8, in year 2021.

I could run `sudo mongod` with sudo privileges but could **not** start it as a service with:  `sudo systemctl start mongod`.

I tried many solutions and tested after each attempt, what ultimately solved it for me is changing ownership of `/data/db/`, `/var/lib/mongo/`, and `/var/log/mongodb/` to `mongod`.

exact commands:

```
sudo chown -R mongod:mongod /var/lib/mongo/
sudo chown -R mongod:mongod /var/log/mongodb/
sudo chown -R mongod:mongod /data/
```